# OpenGL Rotating the Camera in 3D

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, rotation, lwjgl

In OpenGL I have been trying to rotate the camera so I can see the whole 3D Space. I researched rotating the space at the translation point but All I get is the Camera rotating around the center.

Here is the code I am using to rotate the view (in Java):

Game Loop

```
public Game(){
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1280, 720));
        Display.setTitle("Survive the Planets");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Initialize OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50f, 1280f / 720f, 1.0f, 10000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    Planet planet = Planet.generateCreative();
    planet.viewPlanet();

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
        //render
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        planet.render();

        //update
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
            return;
        }

        Camera.rotate(1, 1, 1);

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(240);
    }

    Display.destroy();
}
```

Camera Class

```
public class Camera {

    private static float x, y, z, rX, rY, rZ;

    public static void translate(float x, float y, float z){
        Camera.x += x;
        Camera.y += y;
        Camera.z += z;
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    }

    public static void rotate(float x, float y, float z){
        glRotatef(x, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(y, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(z, 0, 0, 1);

        Camera.rX += x;
        Camera.rY += y;
        Camera.rZ += z;
    }

    public static void setLocation(float x, float y, float z){
        float dx = x - Camera.x;
        float dy = y - Camera.y;
        float dz = z - Camera.z;
        glTranslatef(dx, dy, dz);

        Camera.x = x;
        Camera.y = y;
        Camera.z = z;
    }

    public static void setRotation(float x, float y, float z){
        float dx = x - Camera.rX;
        float dy = y - Camera.rY;
        float dz = z - Camera.rZ;
        glRotatef(dx, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(dy, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(dz, 0, 0, 1);

        Camera.rX = x;
        Camera.rY = y;
        Camera.rZ = z;
    }

}
```

Planet Class:

```
public class Planet {

    private List<Block> blocks;
    private PlanetReference ref;

    private Planet(){ }

    public void render() {
        for(Block block : blocks){
            block.render();
        }
    }

    public static Planet generate(PlanetReference ref){
        Planet p = new Planet();
        p.ref = ref;
        List<Block> blocks = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Block>();

        System.out.println("Genrating planet " + ref.getName() + "... ");

        //world generation
        int r = ref.getRadius() * 32;
        int i = 0;
        for(int x = -r; x != r; x += 32){
            for(int y = -r; y != r; y += 32){
                for(int z = -r; z != r; z += 32){
                    i += 1;
                    Cube cube = new Cube(x, y, z, 32);
                    if(Game.getDistance(cube.getCenter()) < r){
                        Block block = new Block(p, Material.DIRT, cube.getLocation());
                        blocks.add(block);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        p.blocks = blocks;
        System.out.println(blocks.size() + " blocks where generated. " + i);

        return p;
    }

    public void viewPlanet(){
        Camera.setLocation(0, 0, -(ref.getRadius() * 96));
    }

    public static Planet generateCreative() {
        return Planet.generate(new PlanetReference("Creative", 16, 9, 64));
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on what I should do? If you need anymore code just leave a comment.

Comment: If you're doing this to learn, then don't learn all the deprecated methods. Well know about them, but don't use them in practice.

Comment: Could you give me a link to a good tutorial? This is my first time using OpenGL and I don't know a lot of the methods and such. This is how I was taught to do 3D in OpenGL

Comment: Basically all the `glBegin`, `glEnd`, `glVertex`, etc are deprecated since the immediate mode was deprecated, etc. Now you should use VBOs. Also the Matrix Stack is deprecated also because now we are suppose to create, calculate and control our own Matrix Stack. If you aren't good at math, or learning it, then creating and calculating you own Matrix Stack can be a huuuge pain and you might never succeed, but how to calculate a Matrix well Wikipedia can give you the formulas for that.

Comment: Also, if you want to check if you are using deprecated methods easily then you can just create a `ContextAttribs` and pass it too the display when you call `Display.create()`

Comment: Why don't you just use gluLookAt? There is a great free tutorial to learn how things actually work here: www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut